# CSS: 200vw unit not working on mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to do a horizontal slide between two `div`s so here's the html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="viewport-1">
    <div class="inner-div">
      <h1>Viewport background 1</h1></div>
  </div>
  <div class="viewport-2">
    <div class="inner-div">
      <h1>Viewport background 2</h1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i try to container 200vw on with and each div inside the container 100vw the code work fine on desktop view but on mobile is not working at all

[PEN](http://codepen.io/Tipue/pen/pEhvG)

Comment: So have you checked the browser support for that unit? http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Comment: it not working, u can see tht when u try chrome mobile view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about viewport tag? Hope it's help

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: thx a forgot `inistial-scale=1` my previous code was <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> anyway thx again

Answer (score 1):

CSS units vh and vw are not yet widely supported - many browsers don't support it at all, which is most likely the reason your code isn't working on the mobile you're testing it on.
Instead, you should use rem and percentages. You can see an example of this in my fork: http://codepen.io/kvackkvack/pen/mVOePa. I changed the following things:

```
#container {
   ...
   /* (old version) width: 200vh; */
   width: 200rem;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
   ...
}
.viewport-1, .viewport-2 {
  /* (old version) width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh; */
  width: 100rem;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Notice that the percent, while very similar to vw and vh, actually is the full page (even if the page is double the screen-size and scrollable), while vw and vh always are a percent of the screen-size, if you're planning on using that - I'd instead recommend using "rem", which is basically a duplicate of vh. See more about it at https://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/.

Comment: hi ur update work fine for the width but the height it not full

Comment: @John - Hi! I updated my code to use "position: absolute" in the container. This means that you'll have to put "position: relative" in a parent div if you want the container to only take up that element's height (although I can't see that being the case with your already supplied code), but that shouldn't be a problem at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the browser mobile device you are trying to use it on, doesn't support it.

Aside from using vw units, also use percentages, so that you have some backup in case browsers don't support it.

Comment: You should actually consider using `rems` instead. [It's already extremely widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem) with it only not working inside of a `<font>` tag in IE8/9/10.